Spring Boot and Docker Compose cannot access Postgres
I am using Spring Boot 3.3.0 and Docker (version 26.1.3, build b72abbb) on Ubuntu OS. I am using the spring-boot-docker-compose dependency so that Spring Boot starts the Docker image automatically when Spring Boot starts up.
pom.xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

This works as expected, i.e. my Docker image is loaded and the application can talk to the Postgres database.
Problem
When I use a SQL client (e.g. IntelliJ or DBeaver) and try connect to the database, it returns no data. The SQL client is connecting to a different database, when I need it to connect to the same database as the application.
I have read that I need to set the Docker network to:
--network host

Question
This may fix it, but with the Spring Boot dependency above, how do I do this? Or is there an alternative?
More info
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.5'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: ACTIVE_PROFILE
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=expiry_service
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: db

Dockerfile
# Use the Amazon Corretto 21 base image
FROM amazoncorretto:21.0.3

# Create a volume for temporary files
VOLUME /tmp

# Arguments for the JAR file to be copied
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

EXPOSE 8080

# Copy the JAR file into the Docker image
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar

# Set the entry point for the container to run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]

application.properties (that connects the application successfully and retrieves data)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/expiry_service
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

Localhost SQL Client (DBeaver) DB connection that cannot see the data
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/expiry_service
Username: postgres, password: postgres

Here is my container (Docker Desktop):

If I change my DBeaver connection to (port 34881):
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:34881/expiry_service

It gets the following, even though the password is postgres:
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"


I have tried to expose the 5432 port, but it makes no difference.  EXPOSE 8080 EXPOSE 5432 in the Dockerfile.

On a docker bridge network, each container has it's own IP address and localhost means the container itself. You use localhost in your connection string. Try db (the service name of your database) instead, so it becomes jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/expiry_service

I have tried setting the host name to db as you suggest in DBeaver, but it still doesn't connect. The connection attempt failed. db.

Is DBeaver running in a container (in which case it should connect to db:5432) or not (then use localhost and the first ports: number)?  The Docker Desktop screen shot doesn't show the database running.  You should not need to disable Docker networking via network_mode: host for this setup.

Well I guess you are kind of misleading. The dockerfile you are specyfing is the dockerfile for your application. The application runs within a container and the database also runs on its own container. When you are using docker in swarm mode, both containers run in a network together, which means they both can access each other via "localhost". But for your DBeaver, this is not the host network, but another network. Which means, you can either configure it to use host network explicitly, or you connect to your db via its IP explicitly instead of localhost.
docker inspect \
  -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id

Gives you the ip of the container, which you can use in DBeaver to connect to it.

Thanks, am trying that. In my docker-compose.yml it has container_name: db, so I try  docker inspect \   -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' db. However, it returns: Error: No such object: db.

Got it:  docker inspect \   -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' expiry-service-postgres-1 172.20.0.2

DBeaver trying to connect to jdbc:postgresql://172.20.0.2:5432/expiry_service times out.  Connection attempt timed out. Connection attempt timed out.

try using the other port you found out from whatever GUI tool u are using in ur screenshot instead of 5432?
Next time you could offer some more information about what tools exactly you are using, e.g. OS, docker-version, etc.

also you could try to add to any service-definition in your docker-compose "network_mode: host" like in your "app"-service and also in ur "db" service. This should make it use the host network instead of creating its own bridge network so you can use localhost.

I set the db ports to "5431:5432" and network_mode: host, expecting to be able to connect via jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/expiry_service, but that doesn't work. I do however think you are correct that it is a network mapping issue.

That IP address isn't usable on Docker Desktop or other VM-based solutions.  Even if you're using Docker directly on native Linux, you can use localhost and the published port number.  You never need to look this up.
